# Executing jquery code inside angularjs directive templateUrl

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to execute some jquery code inside an angularjs directive html template.
However, the code is inactive.

In the code below, neither `alert("testA");` or `alert("testB");` are called.

I wonder if the mistake I'm doing is to define the jquery calls inside `$(document).ready(function() { /*...*/ }`

Is this what I am doing wrong ? What should I change ?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<span id="testA">testA</span>
<directivecontrol></directivecontrol>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.directive('directivecontrol', function()
{
    return    {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl:  "partials/directive_control.html"
    };
});
```

**partials/directive_control.html**

```
<span id="testB">testB</span>
<script src="js/directive_control.js"></script>
```

**js/directive_control.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#testB").click(function()
    {
        alert("testB");
    });

    $("#testA").click(function()
    {
        alert("testA");
    });
}
```

I'm using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.8 beta under ubuntu 13.04. With angularjs 1.2.0-rc.2 and jquery 1.10.2

Comment: You shouldn't do this. The 'angular way' to do such would be to bind your events in the `link` function of your directive.

Comment: I've put all the code inside the link function and this works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'ready'` event on `document` was already fired well before that `js/directive_control.js` script is loaded, so none of the code in that callback you pass to `$(document).ready` will be executed. But this sort of architecture does not work well with Angular in the first place. You should consider refactoring those click handlers into the linking function for your directive.